How to create a new default project structure for new pyCharm projects?
I would like to always have my new projects contain a src folder, which will contain all my .py scripts. I want this to be done automatically (whenever I create a new project), and don't want to manually add a src folder every time.
The project structure should look like this
Project settings apply to the current project only, as mentioned in the official pyCharm docs
I'm unable to find a way to create my own default project layout.
